# device minSDK is below the used SDK

Tags: android, api, sdk

I've developed an Android application for a device with Android 7.0.

Now I have to test this application with an older device that has Android 4.2.2.

Android Studio shows the following error when trying to deploy: minSDK(API 23) > deviceSDK(API 17).

How I can change the API of my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [**`android:minSdkVersion`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#min).

> An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the
>   application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from
>   installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the
>   value specified in this attribute.

Open ***Module level*** **`build.gradle`** and Set

```
 defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion //
        versionCode //
        versionName "//"
    }
```

After that, **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Comment: @KlingKlang sorry sir.

Comment: Just a distraction. sir

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to `build.gradle` and change the `minSdkVersion` to 17 or lower

```
defaultConfig {
        ..
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ..
        ..
    }
```

Then click on `Sync Now`

This might require downloading missing packages and some changes in your app to support the older version of android

Answer (score 0):

use minSdkVersion to specify the oldest android version your app can support.
For example, if you set your minSdkVersion to 21(Lollipop) then you won't be able to run the app on any phone with android os older than 5.0.
You can find the option to change it in your module level gradle file.

https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers for more details

P.S - I intentionally didn't answer your question.